# I am not able to disable SSL VPN using nodejs. But same code enables SSL VPN. I am passing True/False as parameter flag to my function.

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am not able to disable SSL VPN using nodejs. But same code enables SSL VPN. I am passing True/False as parameter flag to my function.

```
*slClient
        .auth(slUserID, slApiKey)
        .path('User_Customer', userID, 'editObject')
        .parameters([{"sslVpnAllowedFlag":flag}])
        .put()
        .then(res => {
            resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            reject(err);
        });*
```

Comment: ¿Could you please update the question or provide the error it throws when you send it a False?

Comment: It does not show any error. It returns true. But when I check in SL portal I see "SSL" under VPN access not 'None".When I disable SSL VPN from SL portal and try to to enable using api it works. I can see "SSL" under VPN access in SL portal

Answer (score 0):

I did several tests on different test accounts and it works properly either allowing or disabling SSL access, I would suggest to try directly with a rest call directly, for example see below:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/123456489/editObject
```

json Body:

```
{
  "parameters": 
   [
    {
     "sslVpnAllowedFlag":true
    }
   ]
}
```

And refresh the UI after a while, in one of my tests it didn´t throw SSL updated inmediately.

If this doesn´t work, please submit a Ticket for further assistance and add this forum on it.